# How to export directory created inside the Docker image to the host machine?

Tags: linux, unix, docker, permissions, mkdir

The program I'm running inside the Docker image, first creates a directory and writes some file into the directory.

To transfer the directory onto the host machine, I've mounted a `datadir/` and then moved the directory created inside the image into the mounted directory, e.g.:

```
mkdir datadir
DATADIR=datadir/

docker run -i \
-v $(pwd)/$DATADIR:/$DATADIR/ ubuntu \
bash -c "mkdir /x1 && echo 'abc' > x1/test.txt && mv x1 $DATADIR"
```

But when I tried to access `datadir/x1`, it has `root` as the owner and it comes with read-only permissions:

```
$ mv datadir/x1/ .
mv: cannot move 'datadir/x1/' to './x1': Permission denied

$ ls -lah datadir/x1/
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4.0K Jun 28 16:38 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 alvas alvas 4.0K Jun 28 16:38 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      4 Jun 28 16:38 test.txt
```

**Is mounting the additional volume and copying the created directory inside the image the right approach to move files between the Docker image and the host machine?** If not, what's the "canonical" way to perform the same operation?

About the directory permissions, **what should be the correct way to assign the host machine permission to any files inside the mounted volume?**

---

I've tried to `chmod -R 777` inside the Docker image but I don't think that's the safe approach, i.e.:

```
$ docker run -i -v $(pwd)/$DATADIR:/$DATADIR/ -i ubuntu bash -c "mkdir /x1 && echo 'abc' > x1/test.txt && mv x1 $DATADIR && chmod -R 777 $DATADIR"

$ mv datadir/x1/ .

$ ls -lah x1
total 12K
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4.0K Jun 28 16:47 .
drwxrwxr-x 12 alvas alvas 4.0K Jun 28 16:47 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root      4 Jun 28 16:47 test.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid permission issues use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

For example:

```
# This is the directory you want to save the outputs
mkdir datadir

# We create a directory and file inside it, inside the Docker image.
# And we are naming the Docker image "thisinstance"
docker run -i --name thisinstance ubuntu \
bash -c "mkdir /x1 && echo 'abc' > x1/test.txt"

# Copies the new directory inside the Docker image to the host.
docker cp thisinstance:/x1 datadir/

# Destroy the temporary container
docker rm thisinstance

# Check the ownership of the directory and file
ls -lah datadir/x1/
```

[out]:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 alvas  679754705   102B Jun 29 10:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 alvas  679754705   102B Jun 29 10:36 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 alvas  679754705     4B Jun 29 10:36 test.t
```

Comment: But that would mean I need to keep track of the container ID. I just need the output from the container and I don't really want to keep track of what's happening inside Docker.

Comment: Then you have to create in the container the same user that you have in the host machine, and run the commands/create the files with this user. Thus, you will need to [change the user in the docker file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user)

Comment: You say "But that would mean I need to keep track of the container ID" You do not need to do so, you can launch it with `docker run --name mycontainer...` and then you refer to mycontainer, as you can either use the id or the name of a container

Comment: @user2915097 Awesome! Thanks!